# Sort a list for a GridView

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net

I've written the following piece of code to sort my list, which is the data source to my GridView, depending on the column to be sorted on. It seems to me that there is quite a bit of redundancy, and the below code may be optimized. Also, I wanted to apply the strategy pattern (note that I'm just starting out with design patterns), but it seems to me like it would be overkill. Please suggest how the following may be better written.

`User` is my class with several properties, including but not limited to Role, Policy, and Name. The other properties may also be included in this method, so it might grow. `SortingOrder` is an enum with 2 values, Ascending and Descending. `SortExpression` contains the value based on which the data is to be sorted.

```
    private void SortUsers(ref List<User> userList)
    {
        if (SortOrder == SortingOrder.Ascending)
        {
            switch (SortExpression)
            {
                case "Role":
                    userList = userList.OrderBy(user => user.Role).ToList();
                    break;
                case "Policy":
                    userList = userList.OrderBy(user => user.Policy).ToList();
                    break;                   
                default:
                    userList = userList.OrderBy(user => user.Name).ToList();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (SortExpression)
            {
                case "Role":
                    userList = userList.OrderByDescending(user => user.Role).ToList();
                    break;
                case "Policy":
                    userList = userList.OrderByDescending(user => user.Policy).ToList();
                    break;                  
                default:
                    userList = userList.OrderByDescending(user => user.Name).ToList();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of grid-view? WinForms or WPF or anything else?

Comment: ASP.NET.. Anyway, that shouldn't matter, right? Coz the logic here just deals with the sorting based on the SortOrder and the SortExpression.

Comment: _that shouldn't matter_ oh, but how that matters ;-) Many controls support their own sorting interfaces which makes custom sorting like this unnecessary.

Comment: My answer blindly ignores the broader context, but @t3chb0t is absolutely right that you should look at how your other dependencies can help you already, as it may guide how you develop your own abstractions (for example, if it takes a comparer, you will need to think about how you translate a Key and `SortingOrder` into one)

Comment: @t3chb0t Haha my bad. I'm using `TemplateFields` to customize the content shown, so I cannot use the sorting provided out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the prefered way to sort a list is to implement a custom comparer and using `List.Sort`. That also supersede the ugly usage of `ref`:

```
private void SortUsers(List<User> userList)
{
    userList.Sort(new MyCustomComparer(SortExpression, SortOrder ));
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class MyCustomComparer : IComparer<User>
{
    private readonly string mySortExpression;
    private readonly SortingOrder mySortingOrder;

    public MyCustomComparer(string sortExpression, SortingOrder sortingOrder)
    {
        mySortExpression = sortExpression;
        mySortingOrder = sortingOrder;
    }

    public int Compare(User x, User y)
    {
        int compareResult;
        switch (mySortExpression)
        {
            case "Role":
                compareResult = x.Role.CompareTo(y.Role);
                break;
            case "Policy":
                compareResult = x.Policy.CompareTo(y.Policy);
                break;
            default:
                compareResult = x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
                break;
        }       
        return mySortingOrder == SortingOrder.Ascending ? compareResult : -compareResult;
    }
}
```

---

**Why is it ugly to pass reference types by ref?**

Because other references are not updated - they point still to the original object.

The following code illustrates it:

```
void Main()
{
    var array1 = new int[] { 0 };
    var array2 = array1;

    AddOneToEachElement(ref array1);

    // {1}
    array1.Dump("Array1");
    // {0}
    array2.Dump("Array2");
}

private void AddOneToEachElement(ref int[] array)
{
    array = array.Select(i => i + 1).ToArray();
}
```

IMHO ref for reference types should be avoided if possible. If a method create a new object based on another one, it should be named in a propper way (e.g. `CreateXXX`) and return the new instance.

E.g. the following code is much better readable (even if the method name is may not the best one ;)).

```
void Main()
{
    var array1 = new int[] { 0 };
    var array2 = array1;

    array1 = CreateNewArrayAddedOneToEachElement(array1);

    array1.Dump("Array1");
    array2.Dump("Array2");
}

private int[] CreateNewArrayAddedOneToEachElement(int[] array)
{
    return array.Select(i => i + 1).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the correct way to do it. If you could also please elaborate why the usage of `ref` is *ugly*, it would be very helpful.

Comment: @Fahad: see my updated answer :)

Comment: I think I understand now. Both methods update the reference `array1`. However, the first method may or may not update the reference, and there's no way the caller can determine the same. The second method makes the code more readable and gives the caller more flexibility in how they want to handle the result. Thanks for the explanation. :) 
And naming methods (or anything really) is such a pain! :P

Comment: *"the first method may or may not update the reference..."* True but that's what documentation/comments/contracts are for.  *"... and there's no way the caller can determine the same."*  Well, yes there is: `Object.ReferenceEquals`. But it is ugly if I had to do that every time I return from a  method w/ `ref` parameters.

Answer (score 3):

### Repeated Switches

I'm not sure what you mean by Strategy Pattern (never seen the term before), but judging by Wikipedia, I imagine you are referring to the idea of replacing the pair of switch statements, which are liable to fall out of sync and create hard-to-find bugs, with a method to look up the key (e.g. a mapping from `"Role"` to `user => user.Role` and such) and then just switch on the `SortingOrder`, or a method to perform the sort itself (I might be inclined to do both). This is a great idea!

This can be as complex or simple as you like, because it is abstracted away. It should pay off to simply move the existing `switch` into a method:

```c#
delegate IComparable UserKey(User user);

private static UserKey TranslateSortExpression(string sortExpression)
{
    switch (sortExpression)
    {
        case "Role":
            return user => user.Role;
        case "Policy":
            return user => user.Policy;
        default:
            return user => user.Name;
    }
}

private void SortUsers(ref List<User> userList)
{
    UserKey sortingKey = TranslateSortExpression(SortExpression);

    if (SortOrder == SortingOrder.Ascending)
    {
        userList = userList.OrderBy(sortingKey).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        userList = userList.OrderByDescending(sortingKey).ToList();
    }
}
```

A non-obvious benefit of pulling out the expression translator is that by having it return values, the compiler will ensure that it always returns a result. Currently, if you'd added an incomplete code-path by accident you may not notice, as your code would silently fail.

Anyhow, the code remains simple, has definitely become more maintainable, and now you have an obvious place to modify the code (e.g. to if you wanted to look up the `Key` delegate from a dictionary (which could allow you to have 'user keys' or all manner of extensibility)).

### `ref List<User>`

It is clear why you have done this, but it is a tad scary. My first assumption was that this code was performing an in-place sort, and why it is ref isn't necessary clear to the caller (though thankfully C# makes you acknowledge this at the call site).

Unless you have good reason to duplicate the list, you should consider an inplace sort (e.g. using `List.Sort(...)`, though this requires writing a comparer). If not, I would consider changing the method signature so that it takes in one list and `return`s another. As lovely as `ref` variables are, explicitly returning the new list will encourage cleaner calling code (i.e. not reusing a variable name for the unsorted and then sorted list) and make the method behaviour more obvious.

Either way, you should considering adding inline documentation to this method (`\\\ <summary> etc.`) to remind people of the chosen behaviour.

As before, returning also gives the compiler a chance to check you haven't omitted anything. Imagine the misery that could stem from no replacing the list, and finding that some backing list you are expecting to be cloned is being mysteriously modified by some code that is operating on the sorted list (I'm not saying I expect your code will do this, but it's the sort of misery inducing error that can take all day to debug because the code doesn't fail quickly (I'm a big proponent of fail-fast: the best time to fail is at compile time)).

Furthermore, if you return a different list, it can be of a different type. If your signature looked like

```c#
private void IList<User> SortUsers(IReadOnlyList<User> unsortedUserList);
```

then the behaviour becomes apparent (Is it an inplace sort? No, I pass it a readonly list! Where is the output? It's a return value!)

I'll throw in a comment here about using `interfaces` instead of concrete implementations (e.g. `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>`) where possible. It allows people to use their own implementations (which keeps code clean and potentially more efficient) and to exploit type-variant generics (interfaces can be variant, but types cannot (`IList<T>` is invariant, so it doesn't apply here (though `IReadOnlyList<T>` is covariant))

### A word about enums

You should be made aware (if you are not already) that C# `enum`s are not type safe (they are pretty dreadful). You might consider adding an explicit check for `SortingOrder.Descending` and throwing if any other value is passed in (e.g. `(SortingOrder)12`)

### Instance method

Is there a good reason this is an instance method and not a static method? If you can't think of one, then it probably should be static, otherwise another programmer may start to wonder why. Static methods just 'look' honest, because they can't change the state of instances unexpectedly (atleast, not in sane systems).

I don't know enough about the layout of your code to say whether this should or should not be static, but it's worth pondering if you haven't though about it yet.

(I note that `SortExpression` isn't a parameter, so it is presumably an instance member, which may be a good reason to keep this virtual, but again, not enough info in the question for us really to comment on this)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comments. I really like your solution better (and I feel bad for not being able to accept it as the answer :-( ), it's simple and clean, but reading about it further, it seems that implementing `IComparer` is the correct way to go. Also, thank you for your note about `enums` (I did not know this) and static methods, I'll keep them in mind. I'm not entirely convinced about not using `ref`, but I'll keep it in mind. I don't need it for the Sort method anymore, but I have another `Filter()` which has the same signature.

Comment: @Fahad `Comparer` is certainly a good way to go, and Jan's answer is great example!